# Sharepoint block users from creating new lists or libraries

Tags: sharepoint

> I'm an SP site admin. I have a few lists and libraries on the site to control our sales people travels.
> The sales people need to fill in their travel details in a designated list and add relevant docs to a specific library.
>
> I have NO intention to allow any user (=Sales rep) to play around and add **NEW lists/libraries** of their own to the site, nor wiki pages or any other content type!
>
> Is there a way to hide the "New+" button on the home page? or at least block by permissions that ability?

Comment: For the moment, your question has not received an answer. In the meantime, there is a [sister site](sharepoint.stackexchange.com) that specializes in Sharepoint. Try asking the question also there. It may help you to get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the sales people Contribute with no Edit rights for the site. It prevents them from adding anything. They can still fill in a list entry for the travels they been on.

In site settings > People and Groups > Add a new group "Sales" > Give that group Contribute with no Edit permissions > Add the sales people (either by peoplepicker or via Active Directory Groups). That should do the trick.